# Upgrading a Swift 1.1/1.2 project from Xcode 6 to Swift 2 project on Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I have a project that I've been working on with my friend on Swift 1.1/1.2.
Unfortunately, when I upgraded my Xcode to the latest version, I noticed that the app will no longer compile and there are lots of errors.
Is there a way for Xcode 7 to compile for Swift 1.2?
If not, how do I get the old version of Xcode which does not use Swift 2?

Is Swift 2 app backward compatible with Swift 1 apps?
Can Swift 1.2 app run on iOS 9?

Are most developers using the Swift 2 now or not?

Comment: You have to resolve the errors in Xcode 7.

Comment: okay, that seems rather difficult and maybe not a good use of time for now since we're still developing on previous versions of xcode. how do i downgrade to older version of xcode?

Comment: nvm. I found it here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: Move forward, not backward. Support iOS 9. It's pointless to be creating a new app using old tools. Xcode 7 and iOS 9 have been out (in beta) since June.

Comment: @r8bj3k Why to downgrade? Move Forward as said by rmaddy sir.

Comment: Hope you can get answer from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603557/how-to-migrate-my-swift-1-2-project-into-2-0

Comment: i kind of agree with you guys but my friend is a really stubborn dude and he doesn't want to upgrade his goddamn computer which is running mavericks.

Comment: @rmaddy are iOS9 apps written in Xcode7 compatible with iOS8.x? I'm asking because iOS9 adoption is still hovering around 50% worldwide and probably less than 50% in the country i'm targeting.

Comment: An Xcode 7/iOS 9 app can support back to iOS 4.3 if you set the Deployment target of your project appropriately. You just need to make sure newer APIs aren't used on older devices. Please read the "SDK Compatibility Guide" in the iOS docs.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode start with *Edit->Convert->To Latest Swift Syntax...*

You may still have errors that you will have to resolve manually. Read the Xcode Release Notes to see what changed in Swift 2.

[image]

Comment: i tried that but got a bunch of errors which were hard to fix.

Comment: It will get easier as you familiarize yourself with the 2.0 features and changes. The release notes are a good starting point and the effort is well worth it.

Comment: Do you guys think we will have a swift major upgrade every year?